# Rails error tracking with sentry raven-ruby is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sentry, raven

I am trying to use sentry to see log of rails error for my application

Gemfile

```
gem "sentry-raven"
```

application.rb

```
Raven.configure do |config|
   config.dsn = 'dsn url'
end
```

This configuration doesn't seem to work. But when I give explicitly in the code it seems to work.

```
Raven.capture do
  1/0
end
```

Comment: Sentry ignores few errors by default  https://github.com/getsentry/raven-ruby/blob/master/lib/raven/configuration.rb#L160. Are you sure the errors being generated are not one of them?

Comment: Is there any way that I can override the ignore defaults ?

Comment: And I tried for 1/0 error which is not included in IGNORE_DEFAULTS so technically it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the gem better-errors in your Gemfile by any chance?

This interferes somehow with Sentry sending exceptions.